# Laravel 5.1 How to use the same form request rules for two methods when a field is required in one but not in the other method?

Tags: php, forms, validation, laravel, laravel-5.1

I have a form with 3 file input fields and the user should upload at least one file. I have a form request in which I'm validating them as follows:

```
public function rules()
    {
     $this->prepInput();
        return [
            'comment' => 'max:2000',
            'source' => 'different:target',
            'file1'=>'required_without_all:file2,file3|between:1,15360|mimes:txt,pdf',
            'file2'=>'required_without_all:file1,file3|between:1,15360|mimes:txt,pdf',
            'file3'=>'required_without_all:file1,file2|between:1,15360|mimes:txt,pdf'

        ];
    }
```

To update the same form, I'm using `update` method in my controller which is almost the same as `store` method. The only difference is that files are not required in the update form. Is there any way to use the same form request with the `store` and `update` methods and apply the required rule optionally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following trick and it worked:

```
 public function rules()
    {
    $this->prepInput();
        $rules= [
            'comment' => 'max:2000',
            'source' => 'different:target',
            'file1'=>'required_without_all:file2,file3|between:1,15360|mimes:txt,pdf',
            'file2'=>'required_without_all:file1,file3|between:1,15360|mimes:txt,pdf',
            'file3'=>'required_without_all:file1,file2|between:1,15360|mimes:txt,pdf'

        ];
        if($this->myprojects){
            $rules['file1'] = 'between:1,15360|mimes:txt,pdf';
            $rules['file2'] = 'between:1,15360|mimes:txt,pdf';
            $rules['file3'] = 'between:1,15360|mimes:txt,pdf';
        }

          return  $rules;
    }
```

Here my route information are as follows:

```
myprojects/{myprojects}/edit | myprojects.edit | App\Http\Controllers\MyProjectsController@edit
```

So the id of the my `myprojects` entity is `$this->myprojects`. If it is null it is creating a `myprojects`, if it has a value it is updating the corresponding `myprojects`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm basically using an abstract base class for both of my requests, and then add any required rules in subclasses. This will preserve DRY and gives a flexible way to add rules. For example:

```php
abstract class CompanyBaseRequest extends FormRequest
{
    ...
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'category_id' => ['required', 'exists:company_categories,id'],
            'short_description' => ['required', 'string', 'max:2000'],
            'video' => ['nullable', 'file', 'mimes:mp4', 'max:30000'],
        ];
    }
}
```

And then two subclasses:

```php
class CompanyStoreRequest extends CompanyBaseRequest
{
    ...
    public function rules()
    {
        return array_merge(parent::rules(), [
            'logo' => ['required', 'file', 'mimes:png,jpg,jpeg', 'max:1024'],
        ]);
    }
}
```

```php
class CompanyUpdateRequest extends CompanyBaseRequest
{
    ...
    public function rules()
    {
        return array_merge(parent::rules(), [
            'logo' => ['nullable', 'file', 'mimes:png,jpg,jpeg', 'max:1024'],
        ]);
    }
}
```

You should use one of these subclasses where needed, and they both will contain rules from the base class and rules from themselves.

This is better from the accepted answer because the forms themselves are explicitly saying what they do in their name, and don't just work with one condition (which is not clear what they check).

Comment: This is a logical way to accomplish this, and also leverages OOP.

Answer (score 0):

As you are doing like using a method **`$this->prepInput();`** I suggest you change a little bit code to reuse.

1. You have to create named route for both the routes create & edit. I assume you are using resourceful routing
2. Change your code like bellow

   ```
   public function isEditRequestCalled()
   {
     return app('router')->getCurrentRoute()->getName() == 'YOUR_EDIT_ROUTE_NAME';
   }
   ```

and in your request method you change like this

```
    public function rules()
    {
      $this->prepInput();
      return $this->isEditRequestCalled() ? [
        //YOUR EDIT RULES GOES HERE
      ] : [//YOUR CREATE RULES GOES HERE
        'comment' => 'max:2000',
        'source' => 'different:target',
        'file1'=>'required_without_all:file2,file3|between:1,15360|mimes:txt,pdf',
        'file2'=>'required_without_all:file1,file3|between:1,15360|mimes:txt,pdf',
        'file3'=>'required_without_all:file1,file2|between:1,15360|mimes:txt,pdf'

      ];
    }
```

Comment: Yes I'm using resourceful routing. Is there any other solution other than named routes?

Comment: You have to use condition first of all to use it in both actions. So you need a mechanism to distinguish two actions that's why named routes and it's much more easy.

Comment: You use this solutions and inject request class in both store & update method  it's very easy

Answer (score 0):

I use separate `Rule` classes, which basically just store the `$rules` and `$messages` I need for use and reuse in `FormRequest` classes.

```
class RulePrep
{
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    public $rules = [];

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    public $messages = [];
}

class RuleProjects
{
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    public $rules = [];

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    public $messages = [];
}
```

You could try that?
You'd need separate FormRequest classes but it's perhaps neater than all bundled into one with the conditional logic in there.